# How I can extract specific target number from text file

Tags: python, regex

### Input from text file

```
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.150.98 205131102 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.150.100 213131302 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.149.52 205129302 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.149.50 205129102 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.159.38 212134501 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.150.99 205131202 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.150.99 205131212 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1
```

### Expect out out ## --(keep only start "205")

```
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.150.98 205131102 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.149.52 205129302 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.149.50 205129102 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.150.99 205131202 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.150.99 205131212 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1
```

From expect output : I prefer select that row contain number is "205" in the fourth boundary text in row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try a regex approach using `re.search`:

```py
with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if re.search(r'^\S+ \S+ \S+ 205\d+.*$', line, re.M):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Hi,Tim Biegeleisen  I try to codding as your sugest but don't have any reult (empty result)

Comment: @saratoonJ. Try using `re.search` in multiline mode (with the `re.M` flag).

Comment: Now , still not work  don't have any output from them.

Comment: Do this: _Delete_ your images, and instead show us 5 lines from your file, as _text_, along with which of those 5 lines should match.

Comment: @saratoonJ. Please [check this demo](https://rextester.com/PSM52581), where my answer is working.  The only possible doubt is that you are somehow not getting the correct lines out of your text file.

Comment: Ok,I will try again and update to you. Thank you Tim.

Comment: Now is working!!!  , I would change this from "lines = f.read()" to "lines = f.readlines()"   , Thank you for your helpful.